# How can I load iconsmind icons?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Found here those beautiful icons: https://themekit.dev/docs/code/iconsmind/

What do I need to use them? I added following lines to `head`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themekit/css/bootstrap-grid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themekit/css/style.css">

<script src="themekit/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="themekit/scripts/main.js"></script>
```

and this to body:

```
<span className={"im-affiliate"}></span>
```

Nothing appeared.

I expected this icon:

[image]

Comment: The docs show you need an imagesloaded script as well. Also is this a react app or html?

Comment: This is React app. Do you know is it any library in npmjs I can make usage easier?